# Ajax fails when uploading template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this problem, where I am trying to upload a file, and `ajax` fails every time. I am using `ajaxfileupload.js`. Here is the code:

```
$("#importTempButton").click(function(){
        var template =  $('#fileUpload').val();
        if (template != "") {
            $.ajaxFileUpload({
                url: HTTPS + '/lib/model/data/ctlBlog.php?import=1',
                secureuri: false,
                fileElementId: 'fileUpload',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data['results'] == "success") {
                        console.log('WHAT');
                        $("#importList").attr("placeholder", "Template Name");
                        $("#popupDivTempImp").fadeOut();
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data['template']);
                    } else {
                        alert(data['results']);
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#importList").attr("placeholder", "Template Name");
                    alert("Something is wrong with ajax request, please contact administrator!");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please choose template file");
        }
    });
```

All i get is this alert all the time alert:

> Something is wrong with ajax request, please contact.

Okay so this works fine in other page where i do something similar. So my guess is that my controller is broken, but i cant figure out where exactly! Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['import']) && $_GET['import'] == 1){
    $fileUpload = new FileUpload;
    $data = array();

    $uploadResults = $fileUpload->upload("html");
    if ($uploadResults['results'] == "success"){
       $file = $uploadResults['filepath'];
       $data['results'] = "success";
       $data['template'] = file_get_contents($file);
       echo json_encode($data);
       unlink($uploadResults['filepath']); 
    } else {
       $data['results'] = $uploadResults['results'];
       echo json_encode($data);
    }  
}
```

`FileUpload` class works just fine everywhere else. And input file should be html. My guess is that I am doing something wrong with `file_get_contents`, but what exactly...logs don't show antything ether... Please help :)

EDIT: Response Header

age:9232
alternate-protocol:443:quic
date:Thu, 02 Jan 2014 07:06:25 GMT
expires:Fri, 02 Jan 2015 07:06:25 GMT
server:GFE/2.0
status:304 Not Modified
version:HTTP/1.1

Comment: Can you paste a response for this request from the developer console? (You'll find it in "Network" tab)

Comment: Update Error function to get Original Error Message:                                                              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}

Comment: Added Response Header

Comment: @user2945241 Did you update the error: function code & executed again? what message you got in alert box?

Comment: I trying what you said, but getting some errors about that eval!

Comment: Anything? Still having this problem